# xcrun usdz_converter xcode11 not working. how can I fix the issue?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcrun, usdz

Even after updating the directory:
`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

And under xcode/preferences -> command line tools is set to "xcode 11.0 (11a420a)", I am still unable to run `usdz_converter`.

Here's the error message:

```
jorges-iMac:~ jorgeg$ xcrun usdz_converter
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk macosx -find usdz_converter 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "usdz_converter", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Please provide assistance to fix this issue.

Comment: What's the "Connection" with iMacros...!!? - Mention your FCI and post your iMacros Script if relevant or remove that Tag, I don't understand your Qt at all...

Comment: usdz_converter is now depecrated, checkout out this link. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes

Answer (score 6):

As of Xcode 11, usdz_converter is deprecated.
You can download equivalent tooling here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=USDPython.

Once you download and unzip the folder, the easiest way to start using these command-line tools is to double-click USD.command in the Finder. This will open a Terminal window with all necessary environment variables set.

Answer (score -1):

in 2023 to solve this problem just follow these steps

1. go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=USDPython. and download it
2. once you have it downloaded go ahead unzip it and click USD.command (it should open up a terminal)
3. then write usdzconvert -h to see all the commands
4. finally write usdzconvert input-file.obj  output-file.usdz

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution go to `Xcode - Preferences - Locations` and change the Command Line Tools to `Xcode 10`

[image]